# Inadvertent mistake with Jewish books?

Tags: conversion

I recently converted to Islam and have been throwing away books from past study and sinful practices. Some of these are Jewish Kabbalah and Zohar. I started to burn them and realized there were names of God in them. I saved them from the fire until I can get an answer. Have I committed a sin?

Answer (score 1):

No sin incurred. You are fine to proceed and burn them.

We dispose of old Qur'an copies by burning them, too.

Great news to hear about your conversion, Alhamdulillah.

May Allah (ﷻ) bless you.